# Calling codeigniter method from within same controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a method in my controller class, that is performing some actions etc. Now I need to call another method from the same controller that generates a PDF.

But when i call the second method, the first method doesn't complete?

I'm calling the second method like so, so anything below this line doesnt complete:

```
$this->generate_certificate($course_id);
```

Am i missing something? Do i need to call it in a way that doesn't prevent the first method from continuing.

First method, the bit that is related|:

```
else if($progress == 'c') {

                // the course is complete and the user has pressed the complete button
                // on the final page of the course

                // set course as complete in the db, set completed date, set due to next due
                // as defined in course date

                // get todays date
                $todays_date = date("Y-m-d");
                // add specified months on for next due
                $months = $course_object[0]->renewal_period;
                $due_date =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($todays_date . ' + ' . $months .' months'));

                $training_data = array();
                $training_data['user_id'] = $user_id;
                $training_data['course_id'] = $course_id;
                $training_data['due'] = $due_date;

                $this->training_model->set_course_complete($training_data);

                $this->generate_certificate($course_id);

                //certificate generated, redirect to training dashboard
                $view_data = array(
                    'page_title'    => 'Training Dashboard',
                    'user_courses'  => $this->training_model->get_user_courses($user_id),
                );

                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'You have successfully completed this course!');

                $this->load->view('training/training_dashboard',$view_data);


            }
```

Generate PDF method:

```
private function generate_certificate($course_id) {

    $this->load->model('org_model');
    $this->load->model('user_model');

    // get todays date
    $todays_date = date('d F Y');

    // get currently logged in user details
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $user_object = $this->user_model->get_user($user_id);
    $users_name =  $user_object[0]->first_name . " " . $user_object[0]->last_name;

    // course data
    $course_object = $this->training_model->get_course_data($course_id);

    // get org name
    $org_id = $this->session->userdata('org_id');
    $org_name_object = $this->org_model->get_org_name($org_id);
    $org_name = $org_name_object[0]->org_name;

    $html=" // I've removed this as its large, but works perfectly // ";

    //this the the PDF filename that user will get to download
    $pdfFilePath = "Certificate.pdf";

    //load mPDF library
    $this->load->library('m_pdf');

    //generate the PDF from the given html
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);

    //download it.
    $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "D");
}
```

Comment: can you give us the code of your two methods, please?

Comment: Added to original post

Comment: From where did you get the `$course_id` ?

Comment: Its fed into the start of the first method. The first method runs fine, the second method runs fine I have tested both separately and they work fine. It is only when I add the call to the second method that the first method doesnt complete. Why does it stop the rest of the method running?

Comment: can you give the var_dumo of `$org_name_object`, please

Comment: Theres nothing wrong with the data in that var

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117826/discussion-between-frobak-and-elddenmedio).

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method in a model that generate the PDF. You can call other models methods in a model, so you can place the generate_certificate method in a new model. Then load that model in the controller and call that method.

That won't break the execution.

Further, if you need a single method to only generate the PDF, call the model method too.